# Load Spring Boot application properties from external file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a problem connected with loading application.yml settings from external file. I have normal JHipster monolith app with some additional settings. So I am using ApplicationProperties class. And it is working correctly, when properties are loaded from application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml. 
But there is a problem, when I want to change some properties related to env. So I created application.yml file, located next to war/jar file. Everything except my custom ApplicationProperties class is loaded, so for example current  profile.
What can be wrong?

To clarify:
I have normal JHipster application, where is also ApplicationProperties class. I have declared another class to store my additional properties. And there is problem with loading that additional class, when I put application.yml or application.properties "outside" src directory. 
My goal is to place application.properties or application.yml outside WAR file and get my properties loaded correctly.

Comment: Just trying to understand your question. Do you want to load yml file which is not under 'src' directory?

Comment: Yes. I have added some additional data about the problem. My goal is to store some env properties outside WAR file (so not under src file). It is better for my, because I need to use one version of application on different servers with different configuration.

Comment: Your Statement: "I need to use one version of the application on different servers with different configuration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your question as well as comment, I can suggest a few things to try.

- So, you can create a few files like `application-prod1.yml` and
  `application-prod2.yml`
- Then delete/remove your application.yml file.
- While running your app in server, declare spring profile as prod1 or prod2

Not loading your main `application.yml` file will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, it can help, but I think that it is not a great solution. Better option is to handle external application.yml and load settings from external file.